# Could not load file or assembly 'Serilog.FullNetFx, Version=1.5.0.0'

Tags: serilog

I have .Net 4.5.2 application and I have installed `Serilog 2.1.0`  and  `Serilog.Sinks.MongoDB 2.0.19` I have configured sink as

```
   var log = new Seri.LoggerConfiguration()
       .WriteTo.MongoDBCapped("mongodb://localhost:27017/test",collectionName: "logs")
       .CreateLogger();
```

However I am getting error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Serilog.FullNetFx, Version=1.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.":"Serilog.FullNetFx, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB sink was only updated a day ago to support Serilog 2.0. You need to run:

```
Update-Package Serilog.Sinks.MongoDB
```